# Добавление фона в 2D игре Юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется 2D игра пинг понг в Юнити, есть две ракетки и шарик, у них имеются добавленные в папку assets спрайты, но фон у игры стандартного синего света, однако при попытке изменения фона на добавленную в ту же папку картинку возникает проблема, что она накладывается поверх имеющихся ракеток и шарика на всю сцену и возникает следующая повторяющаяся ошибка:
ArgumentException: Input Button Submit is not setup.
To change the input settings use: Edit -> Settings -> Input

Попытка добавления фона заключалась в следующем: В окне с MainCamera и GameManager нажимал правую кнопку мыши и выбирал UI затем Image. Потом в инспекторе для Image в поле Source Image выбираю добавленное изображение, во вкладке Rect Transform растягиваю картинку на всю сцену. В чем может быть ошибка и как еще тогда можно добавить фон в данном случае? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант делать отдельный Canvas с Image и поставить значение Order in layer поменьше.

Ошибка появляется скорее всего из-за того, что используемая в каком-нибудь скрипте кнопка не настроена в Input Manager.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html